# How to fix circular importing?

Tags: django

It seems I have a circular importing error. I currently just struggling to fix it. Does anyone know what I should do?

In my models.py, containing ReservedItems & Order:

```
def reserveditem_pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.order_reference:
        instance.order_reference = unique_order_reference_generator()
```

In my utils.py

```
from lumis.utils import get_random_string
from .models import Order, ReservedItem


def unique_order_reference_generator():

    new_id = get_random_string(length=10)

    reserved_item = ReservedItem.objects.filter(
        order_reference=new_id
    ).exists()
    order = Order.objects.filter(order_reference=new_id).exists()

    if reserved_item or order:
        return unique_order_reference_generator()
    else:
        return new_id
```

Comment: Import it locally.

Comment: You could move `reserveditem_pre_save_receiver ` into `utils.py`. The [docs recommend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions) that you move your signals out of `models.py`.

Comment: That's interesting. Haven't read that before. And pre_save.connect(reserveditem_pre_save_receiver, sender=ReservedItem) I will keep in my modely.py, right? Would you move it to utils.py or create a new signals.py?

Comment: Moving it to `signals.py` instead of `utils.py` might be more conventional, but I think either would work in this case. The key thing is to move it out of models to prevent the circular import. The `connect()` should be moved out of models as well (either into the same module as `reserveditem_pre_save_receiver`, or the app's `ready()` method).

Comment: @Alasdair I am currently trying to do it without the ready(). I moved all reserveditem_pre_save_receiver & connect() to my signals.py

However, when I am creating a new object, my pre_save is completely ignored. Somehow it doesn't surprise me, because I don't "tell" models.py that I have a signals.py. Do I somehow have to import anything in my models.py? Or is the ready() necessary? Sorry all my questions, but I learned pre_save so far only with models.py so that new approach is still a bit confusing to me.

Comment: This is getting off topic for the question. You need to import signals somewhere, otherwise `connect()` will never run. The recommended place to do this is in the `ready()` method. If you don't want to do that, then you need to import it somewhere else (e.g. `models.py`), but that might lead to circular dependencies.

Comment: After I found one more explanation (see below) I finally understood it. Also thank you to @Willem Van Onsem you link to GitHub was also very helpful. Again, thank you so much to all of you for your help.  https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **import modules *locally*** in the body of the function, so:

```
from lumis.utils import get_random_string


def unique_order_reference_generator():
    from .models import Order, ReservedItem

    new_id = get_random_string(length=10)

    reserved_item = ReservedItem.objects.filter(
        order_reference=new_id
    ).exists()
    order = Order.objects.filter(order_reference=new_id).exists()

    if reserved_item or order:
        return unique_order_reference_generator()
    else:
        return new_id
```

This thus means that the module is *not* loaded when Python loads the file, but when the function is actually called. As a result, we can load the `unique_order_reference_generator` function, without having to load a the module that actually depends on this function.

Note that, like @Alasdair says, signals are typically defined in a dedicated file (`signals.py`) for example which should be loaded in the `ready()` function of the app. But regardless how you structure code, frequently local imports should be used to avoid circular imports.

Comment: Oh wow, I wasn't even aware of that is possible. Thank you very much!

Comment: So local import worked perfect. I am now just trying to understand the second approach which Alasdair and Mad Wombat are also referring to.

I moved reserveditem_pre_save_receiver and pre_save.connect in my new signals.py. The next step, how to load this in ready(), and make it functioning I didn't understand yet. Where do I define this ready function?

Comment: @JonProgrammer: see here: https://gist.github.com/kylefox/177091bd8e4d88ac0cc19496064fd7d3 Note that this does not *per se* removes the cyclic import, it is more the advisable structure of Django apps.

Answer (score 2):

All the current suggestions are good. Move your signal handlers out of models. Models are prone to circular imports because they are used everywhere, so it is a good idea to keep only model code in models.py.

Personally, I don't like imports in the middle of the code

> import-outside-toplevel / Import outside toplevel

Instead I use Django application API to load models without importing

```
from django.apps import apps

def signal_handler(instance, *args, **kwargs):
    Order = apps.get_model('your_app', 'Order')
    ...
```

Comment: I've tried also the [answer from Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50861104/5675325) and decided to go with yours  since it's also the preferred way in pylint. (+1)